# Nautilus Hide context menu not working

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 21.04

Recently updated Ubuntu to 21.04 and the context menu `Hide/Show Files` options no longer appear. I can still show / hide hidden files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or through the options.

Comment: It's in the main menu.

Comment: What is, where is the main menu, and how do I get there? Because it's not in preferences or GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: Did you install nautilus-hide

Comment: Yes I did, of course. -_- Have latest version (0.2.3-8)